# Why protoc executable fails to run from Gradle on GitHub Action?

Tags: java, github-actions

I have a `ubuntu-latest` GitHub action which builds a project using Gradle.

One of the Gradle tasks is a `JavaExec` task which runs a code generator:

```
task("generateCode", JavaExec::class) {
  mainClass.set("code.generator.Main")
  classpath = generateCodeClasspath
}
```

Recently the Java application has been modified to download a binary (`protoc`), copy it to the file system and execute it. "It works on my machine", but it fails on GitHub Action and I can't find out why.

The `protoc` binary is downloaded to `/home/runner/work/project/project/submodule/build/protoc/bin`.
Immediately before the JVM attempts to spawn the `protoc` process, file exists and is executable:

`stat protoc`

```
  File: protoc
  Size: 4539800     Blocks: 8872       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 1822895     Links: 1
Access: (0744/-rwxr--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/  runner)   Gid: (  121/  docker)
Access: 2022-03-14 14:51:45.943750443 +0000
Modify: 2022-03-14 14:51:45.979750853 +0000
Change: 2022-03-14 14:51:45.979750853 +0000
 Birth: -
```

`ldd protoc`

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd43ba6000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc367fd3000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc367fb0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc367dbe000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc368133000)
```

The program is started with ProcessBuilder using these arguments:

```
ProcessBuilder(
              "protoc",
              "--proto_path",
              intermediateProtoDir.absolutePath,
              "--plugin",
              binDir.resolve("proto-gen-rust").absolutePath,
      )
```

However, running `protoc` fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "protoc" (in directory "/home/runner/work/project/project/submodule/build/protoc/bin"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess you are missing that "executable exists" isn't the same as "executable is on PATH".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it, you change into the particular directory (`/home/runner/work/project/project/submodule/build/protoc/bin`) before trying to execute it? Then I believe the program is not found because the current working directory is not in your `$PATH` and you are not specifying an absolute path in your call.

Try either adding `/home/runner/work/project/project/submodule/build/protoc/bin` to your `$PATH` or change `"protoc"` to `"./protoc"` in your call:

```
ProcessBuilder(
              "./protoc",
              "--proto_path",
              intermediateProtoDir.absolutePath,
              "--plugin",
              binDir.resolve("proto-gen-rust").absolutePath,
      )
```

Comment: Changing `protoc` to `./protoc` solved the issue for me. Apparently it worked locally because protoc was also installed in the user bin. Thank you!